# Notification Icon is orange

Tags: android, notifications, icons

[image: Here's the icon!]

Im using notification manager to put an on going notification, but it's icon when you scroll down the UI menu is full orange, anyone know why?

```
Builder montaNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                                                    .setContentTitle(tickerText)
                                                    .setContentText(message)
                                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                                                    .setContentIntent(aoSelecionar);
```

Comment: full orange? can you attach your drawable?

Comment: added the icon that i'm using...

Comment: And are you talking about the UI in the app or for your notification? And what kind of phone/tablet are you using?

Comment: Moto G, android 4.4.4... The icon shown at the left side of the notification description, its all orange/yellow...

Comment: Can u provide a screenshot

Comment: solved right now... the image must be in 36px x 36px...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, you must resize your image to 36px x 36px

Comment: All this information is right in google's developer docs for design http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html and this information you have provided is not correct. The exact image size is based on dp not pixels. Even if this does work for you, this may not scale well on higher resolution devices.